# You don't have access to the Default Directory org in Teams. Select another org, or contact your admin for more details.(Microsoft Teams)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

My project is working include microsoft Teams version latest and Microsoft Auze's service Graph API with my account's role team manage on Potal Azure .
I have two Tenant ID : one Default Directory Guest and Default Directory org but currently, when I login microsoft Teams it just only access to Default Directory Guest, I can't switch to Default Directory org because it does not has option . Please refer to the attached image this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/6i0Ei.png, I have to solve how does I can swith to Default directory another?

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to us We will investigate and if we require further information we will reach out. Best regards, Teams Platform

Comment: thanks @Abhijit-MSFT ,I am still urgently looking for a solution .

Comment: What type of your account to the Default Directory org? A guest or a member?

Answer (score 0):

check is there any conditional access policy created for the end user application.[image]

Comment: Thank you Kartheek R , I contacted with Admin and they removed my account and added again , currently it worked good .